# Why, in Millikan's oil drop method, the drop is suspended whereas normally it moves with terminal velocity

Tags: charge, voltage

I just don't understand how the voltage is adjusted to suspend the droplet. What do we use to adjust the voltage? Because, normally, even when electric and gravitational forces are balanced, the charge will moves with uniform velocity towards the oppositely charged direction.

Comment: The drop wants to fall vertically under the force of gravity. If the drop is charged and between two metal plates you can apply sufficient voltage across the plates such that the electrostatic force counterbalances the gravitational force and the drop can be made to hover in space. Electrostatic forces want to pull it up, gravity wants to pull it down, and they cancel each other out.

Comment: If this is still unclear to you, I recommend that you draw the free body diagram of a droplet in the case of balanced forces.

Comment: in your argument you don't take in account air friction which is important in this experiment. But usually it is very difficult to get a droplet suspended, so you measure its velocity up and down chanching the direction of E between.

Comment: have you read this  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment